# Algorithm to process a circular group

Tags: algorithm

Noob here, sorry if this is a too silly question. Only I am looking to the name of the algorithm. because I am pretty sure someone solved this problem before, but I cannot found anything on google, mostly because of a lack of vocabulary.
Basically, what I am looking, is the best algorithm to solve the following situation:
I have a group of elements, let say Companies. I need to process all of them, one by one, but the criteria are that the next one will be the least attended. For example, if my universe where 3 companies:

- Oracle
- Apple
- Google

The first time, whichever of those will fulfill the criteria, so let's say we choose Oracle. We process Oracle, so in the next round it will be or Apple or Google, but clearly not Oracle. Let's choose now Apple. The next round is clearly Google. When I finished the first round, I need to attend them again, this time, I do not need to choose at random, because of the 3 companies, Oracle was processed the most time ago.

I am sure there is a well known algorithm for this

Comment: am not sure I understood you correctly, but I think you need least used first right? if that is the case then I would suggest to use First-in-Last-out Algorithm and re-inserting the element when accessed.

Comment: A `Queue` where you pull elements from the front and put them back on at the end of the list? In a database you might simply add a timestamp field 'LastUsed' and sort by that to find the next one to process again.

Comment: "round-robin" may be the term you are looking for.

Comment: thanks!! that was precisely what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

As @Henry mentioned in the comments, the answer to my question is "Round Robin"